# If $\dim({\rm Im}(T))$ and $\dim({\rm Ker}(T))$ are finite $\Longrightarrow$ $\dim(V)$ is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let be $F$ a field, $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $F$. Prove that
> if it exist a linear tranformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ with
> $\dim({\rm Im}(T))$ and $\dim({\rm Ker}(T))$ both finite, then $\dim(V)$ is finite.

What we know is that:

- There exists a finite set of vectors $\left \{ v_1,...,v_n \right \}$ such that generates ${\rm Ker}(T)$
- There exists a finite set of vectors $\left \{ w_1,...,w_m \right \}$ such that for each one exists $u_i \in V$, such that $T(w_i)=u_i$

Since there exists a finite quantity of $u_i \in V $ such that $T(w_i)=u_i$, and $\dim({\rm Ker}(T))<\infty$, then $\dim(V)$ must be finite. But I'm not sure about how can I conclude, can you help me please?

Comment: Careful, the second bullet point could be false. There may be infinitely many elements $w_i$ and $u_i$ such that $Tu_i = w_i$. What we know is that the **dimension** of $\text{im} \ T$ is finite.

Comment: Okey I understand that. Thank you so much, but how can I concluye that $Dim(V)$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** proceed as in the usual proof that $\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim \text{im} \ T$, that is, consider a basis $B_0$ of $\ker T$ and extend it to a basis $B$ of $V$. Now, show that the image of $B \setminus B_0$ is a basis for $\text{im} \  T$.

> These remarks and the hypothesis tells us that both $B_0$ and $B\setminus B_0$ must be finite, hence the basis $B$ of $V$ is finite. This completes the proof.

Comment: $B\setminus B_0 \subset V$. Is it a basis for $\operatorname{im} T$? You mean the image of $B \setminus B_0?$

Comment: @Saikat I wrote 'the image of $B\setminus B_0$', yes.

Comment: But the $ImT$ is contained in $W$. So, the basis of $ImT$ must be in $W$, or not?

Comment: Indeed, since $B \setminus B_0 \subset V$, we have $T(B \setminus B_0) \subset T(V) \subset W$.

Comment: @guidoar: Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: Okey! Thanks you very very much. Can you give me any suggestion to prove that the image of $B$ less $B_0$ is a basis for $ImT$? (please)

Comment: Sure. What have you tried?

Comment: We know that the image of $B_0$ is just \left \{  0 \right \}. So, image of $ B / B_0$ should generates $W / \left \{ 0  \right \}$, and that is equal to a basis of the Image of $T$... Am I correct? Sorry, I'm new at linear algebra

Comment: There's nothing to apologize for! Careful, it is true that $T(B_0) = 0$, but $B \setminus B_0$ need not generate the whole space $W$. It does generate the image of $T$. Take $x$ in the image. By definition, we have $x = T(y)$ for some $y \in V$. Write $y$ in base $B$, and try to derive from that the fact that $y$ is actually a linear combination of the vectors in $T(B\setminus B_0)$. Here you will need to use, as you correctly point out, that $T(B_0) = 0$. Now you have to deal with linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

By the *first isomorphism theorem*, $V/\ker T\cong\rm{im}\,T$.  Thus $\dim V=\dim(\rm{im}\,T)+\dim(\ker T)\lt\infty$.